# how to make a symbolic link to a folder at first logon

Tags: command-line, users, configure

I have an Ubuntu 18.04.3 installation with 20 users (no superusers) and I just copied 2 pdf files in the `/usr/share/coure_share/` folder where everybody has access to. I want to make a symbolic link on that folder to every user at first login. Now I've red on forums that to make a symbolic link one can put a script.sh file in the `/etc/profile.d/` folder. This is what I did so I wrote this in a share.sh file which I put there:

```
ln -sfn /usr/share/course_share /home/userxx/Desktop/course_share
```

But at first login of any user I get the message "/home/userxx/Desktop/course_share" "Faile to create symbolic link. No such file or directory". When I do it later (when I logged in and opened the shell) it works perfectly. I guess at first login the desktop folder is not created but I am not shure. 
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the scripts in `/etc/profile.d` are executed before `xdg-user-dirs-update` creates the folders for the new user. One possible solution would be to create the `Desktop` folder in `/etc/skel`. Your script should now work for newly created users.

Also, is `chmod -R a+rwx /home/userxx/Desktop`really necessary in your case?

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. The thing is that the /etc/skel only copies the files inside in the root folder when we create a new user. I just tested it. It doesn't actually excecute the shell script.

Comment: No, and it's not supposed to. It's just to help mitigate the fact, that your script runs before the symlink can be created at all.

Comment: Hi. Oh I understood now. When we create the /etc/skel/Desktop Folder. The shell script in etc/profile.d recognizes the path and creates the link. Thanks a lot. That was it.